# JPanel set to invisible, combobox choice other than default sets it to visible, but components are missing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, visibility, jcombobox

I am building an ohms law app. Please keep in mind that is my first program ever (without tutorials) so please be kind =) Here's how it looks when you run it:

[image: http://imgur.com/QYe4V]

The combo box has options to calculate volts, calculate ohms, etc...

The center panel is set to invisible until you make a choice from the combobox. Here's what it should look like when you make a selection:

[image: http://imgur.com/ZlWJX]

The problem I am facing, is that the **first** time I make a selection, only one of the JLabel/JTextArea combos (each pair is on its own panel inside a vertical box) are displayed:

[image: http://imgur.com/vNYX1]

If i click the comboBox and make the same selection again, it displays correctly. I can't figure out why it acts incorrectly on the first click. Perhaps I am taking the wrong approach in building the GUI. Here's the code so far:

```
private JFrame frame;
private String[] choiceList = {"", "Calculate Volts", "Calculate Amps", "Calculate Ohms", "Calculate Watts"};
private JTextField textField_2;
private JPanel centerPanel;
private String volts = "Volts";
private String amps = "Amps";
private String ohms = "Ohms";
private String watts = "Watts";
private JLabel var1Label;
private JLabel var2Label;
private JLabel var3Label;
private JFormattedTextField var1TextField;
private JFormattedTextField var2TextField;
private JFormattedTextField var3TextField;



/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GUI window = new GUI();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public GUI() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("BotsOne ElectriCalc");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
    northPanel.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    northPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
    frame.getContentPane().add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JLabel choiceLabel = new JLabel("Please make a selection:");
    northPanel.add(choiceLabel);

    JComboBox choiceCombo = new JComboBox(choiceList);
    northPanel.add(choiceCombo);
    choiceCombo.addActionListener(new ChoiceComboListener());

    JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
    southPanel.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    southPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
    frame.getContentPane().add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Answer:");
    southPanel.add(label);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setColumns(10);
    southPanel.add(textField_2);

    centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.setVisible(false);
    centerPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
    frame.getContentPane().add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    Box centerPanelVertBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
    centerPanelVertBox.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    centerPanel.add(centerPanelVertBox);
    centerPanelVertBox.setVisible(true);
    centerPanelVertBox.setBorder(null);

    JLabel pleaseEnterLabel = new JLabel("Please enter 2 of 3 values:");
    pleaseEnterLabel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(15, 0, 10, 0));
    pleaseEnterLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    centerPanelVertBox.add(pleaseEnterLabel);

    JPanel var1Panel = new JPanel();
    centerPanelVertBox.add(var1Panel);

    var1Label = new JLabel("xxx");
    var1Label.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    var1Panel.add(var1Label);

    var1TextField = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getInstance());
    var1TextField.setColumns(10);
    var1Panel.add(var1TextField);

    Panel var2Panel = new Panel();
    centerPanelVertBox.add(var2Panel);

    var2Label = new JLabel("xxx");
    var2Label.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    var2Panel.add(var2Label);

    var2TextField = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getInstance());
    var2TextField.setColumns(10);
    var2Panel.add(var2TextField);

    Panel var3Panel = new Panel();
    centerPanelVertBox.add(var3Panel);

    var3Label = new JLabel("xxx");
    var3Label.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    var3Panel.add(var3Label);

    var3TextField = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getInstance());
    var3TextField.setColumns(10);
    var3Panel.add(var3TextField);

    Panel calculatePanel = new Panel();
    centerPanelVertBox.add(calculatePanel);

    JButton calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");
    calculatePanel.add(calculateButton);
}

public class ChoiceComboListener implements ActionListener {    //combobox actionlistener

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)ev.getSource();
        String currentComboSelection = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
        if (currentComboSelection.equals(choiceList[1])) {                  //choice 1 (Calculate Volts)
            centerPanel.setVisible(true);
            var1Label.setText(amps);
            var2Label.setText(ohms);
            var3Label.setText(watts);               
            //centerPanel.repaint();                
        }
        if (currentComboSelection.equals(choiceList[2])) {                //choice 2 (Calculate Amps)
            centerPanel.setVisible(true);
            var1Label.setText(volts);
            var2Label.setText(ohms);
            var3Label.setText(watts);
            centerPanel.repaint();              
        }
        if (currentComboSelection.equals(choiceList[3])) {
            centerPanel.setVisible(true);
            var1Label.setText(volts);
            var2Label.setText(amps);
            var3Label.setText(watts);
        }
        if (currentComboSelection.equals(choiceList[4])) {
            centerPanel.setVisible(true);
            var1Label.setText(volts);
            var2Label.setText(amps);
            var3Label.setText(ohms);
        }
        if (currentComboSelection.equals(choiceList[0])) {
            centerPanel.setVisible(false);
            //centerPanel.repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

If you look at the bottom, there is an inner class called ChoiceComboListener, this is the comboBox listener, I have tried playing around with repaint(), and various other things, but I can't come up with anything. Any help, guidance, or criticism is appreciated.

Comment: "Please keep in mind that is my first program ever (without tutorials)"  -- Well done, well done.

Comment: @Bots Please post your comment as an answer and mark it as the answer

Answer (score 3):

> Any help, guidance, or criticism is appreciated

Another opton might be to use a [Card Layout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). The tutorial has a working example that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

"Please keep in mind that is my first program ever (without tutorials)"  -- Well done, well done.  One suggestion is that you may wish to consider making your electrical units into an enum as they seem a perfect place to practice this important concept.  Also, you JTextFields may line up better with a GridBagLayout, but it can be **very** persnickety to use.

e.g., on enum:

```
enum ElectricalUnits {
   AMPS("Amps"), OHMS("Ohms"), WATTS("Watts"), VOLTS("Volts");

   private String text;
   private ElectricalUnits(String text) {
      this.text = text;
   }
   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }
   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return text;
   }
}
```

Then the users choice can be an enum, and this may simplify some of the code in your gui's logic portion.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had the first panel (the one that was displaying correctly) declared as a JPanel, and I declared the other 2 as regular Panels. Sheesh! Anyways if anyone wants to supply some advice or criticism it's still welcomed! – Bots